# Есть что-то по типу None для вектора

Tags: c++, функции, vector

Я хочу это передать как значение по умолчанию. Например:

```
void test(int r, std::vector<std::vector<int>> = ?){
....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пустой вектор устроит?

```
void test(int r, std::vector<int> = std::vector<int>())
{  
}
```

Comment: Блин точно, чёт я тупанул, спасибо.